# A function I created can only be called once, second time it shows an error

Tags: function, turtle-graphics

I created a function to draw a bargraph with turtle. The first call works fine but fails when calling it for the second time:

> "File "C:\Users\NTC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc    raise Terminator turtle.Terminator"

only thing i tried is using t.terminator at the end, same results

```
    def bar_chart():
        t = turtle.Turtle()
        screen = turtle.Screen()
        ##snip  # lines detailing the lines drawing
        for value in range(1,11): # the upper limit has to be more thanhighest value in the "count"
            t.forward(20)
            t.write((" " + str(value)), align="left",font=("Arial", 8,     "normal"))
        screen.exitonclick()
```

just expect it to be called multiple times in a looped program.

Answer (score 0):

The `screen.exitonclick()` function has no business being in a function that you plan to call multiple times.  It's logically the last thing you do in your program.  You also shouldn't keep allocating turtles to do the same thing, allocate one and reuse it.  Something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def bar_chart(t):
    for value in range(1, 11): # the upper limit has to be more than highest value in the "count"
        t.forward(20)
        t.write((" " + str(value)), align="left", font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

bar_chart(turtle)

screen.exitonclick()
```